# Table going past margins

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, margins

I'm trying to create a header for my resume. I'm almost happy with the result, but there's a small formatting issue. 
I'm using a table to control where my name and contact info are placed. My name and details are just long enough to go slightly over my margins, and look a little awkward. Here's the minimum to show what I'm working with.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moresize}    
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l r l}
\Huge{White H. Love-Tiger} &  & \\ \hline
 & \small{\tt{whlt@stackexchange.com}} & \small{42 Latex Ave.}\\
 & \small{(555) 765-4321} & \small{Texburg, \textsc{XY}}\\
 &  & \small{\textsc{A1A 1A1}} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}      

\section*{Experience}
Latex expert: I've never needed to ask anyone for help with Latex because I'm sure a Latex expert. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. I'm the most amazing, you really need to hire me, blah blah blah.... please give me a job. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish.

\end{document}
```

The header goes just past the right margin. Is there a way I could have the header table fill the document from the left margin to the right margin, and have the lower rows of contact information not go past the right margin? This means that the end of my name might hang over the beginning of my email address, but I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe (your code commented from time to time to see the differences):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moresize}    
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{droidsans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\overfullrule5pt

\begin{document}

%\begin{table}
%\begin{tabular}{l r l}
%\Huge{White H. Love-Tiger} &  & \\ \hline
\leftline{\Huge{White H. Love-Tiger} }\vspace{-2mm} % as much as you wish

\noindent
\null\hrulefill

\rightline{%
\begin{tabular}{r l}
% & \small{\tt{whlt@stackexchange.com}} & \small{42 Latex Ave.}\\
\small{\tt{whlt@stackexchange.com}} & \small{42 Latex Ave.}\\
% & \small{(555) 765-4321} & \small{Texburg, \textsc{XY}}\\
 \small{(555) 765-4321} & \small{Texburg, \textsc{XY}}\\
% &  & \small{\textsc{A1A 1A1}} \\
& \small{\textsc{A1A 1A1}} \\
\end{tabular}%
}
%\end{table}      

\section*{Experience}
Latex expert: I've never needed to ask anyone for help with Latex because I'm sure a Latex expert. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. I'm the most amazing, you really need to hire me, blah blah blah.... please give me a job. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish. Blah blah blah blah, lorem ipsum gibberish gibberish gibberish.

\end{document}
```

And better `\LaTeX\ Ave.` instead of `Latex Ave.`, but I understand that your text is a pretty joke.

Comment: This completely fixes my problem. Thank you very much. And yes, if I actually did live on Latex Ave., you can bet I would indicate it as \LaTeX Ave. on all correspondence.